# Programa buscador de páginas de um website em Python

Tags: python

Quero escrever um código em Python que acesse determinado site colocando uma lista de palavras no final da URL para achar as páginas do site, com um temporizador. Eu fiz porém ele não me retorna o nome das páginas. Aqui está o código:

```
import requests
import time

list = open('lista.txt')
lista = list.read()
list.close

for linha in lista.split('\n'):
     response = requests.get('https://www.nomedosite.com'.format(linha))
     time.sleep(3)

     if response.status_code == '200' :

       print response
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe um erro no seu código. Falta indicar o local onde será injetado o valor da variável *linha* na url.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.nomedosite.com/{}'.format(linha))
```

Comment: caramba verdade kkk mais mesmo assim nao esta funcionando